# Linear Dependence and Coefficient of Zero

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

I was wondering by linear dependence, if it actually means at least TWO of the coefficients are nonzero? Since it cannot be one coefficient is nonzero and the other terms are all 0, then the sum of all $c_ix_i$ would not equal to 0 in the end.

Comment: what if $x_i=0$?

Comment: i meant for all nonzero vectors

Answer (score 0):

I see in the comments that you clarify that this is for all nonzero vectors, which would make your thought process correct.

You could only have one nonzero coefficient if the zero vector was in the set of vectors you were considering. If that were the case, its coefficient could be any number except zero, resulting in linear dependence.